# Ruby on Rails 3.1, Ckeditor custom toolbars. Where to place definitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I used the gem to install ckeditor.  As such there is no config.js in the project (there is in the actual gem folder that I don't want to modify).  The install did create a ckeditor.js in the config/initializers folder that would seem to be the correct place to put the tool bar definition.  But everything I have tried to get that to work throws a variety of syntax or method not found errors.  Has anyone had success with this?  If so a quick example would be very helpful.

My current ckeditor.js is:

```
# Use this hook to configure ckeditor
if Object.const_defined?("Ckeditor")
  Ckeditor.setup do |config|

  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default), :mongo_mapper and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require "ckeditor/orm/active_record"

  # Allowed image file types for upload.
  # Set to nil or [] (empty array) for all file types
  # config.image_file_types = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif", "tiff"]

  # Allowed attachment file types for upload.
  # Set to nil or [] (empty array) for all file types
  # config.attachment_file_types = ["doc", "docx", "xls", "odt", "ods", "pdf", "rar", "zip", "tar", "swf"]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem as yours. At first, I followed [Config rails with asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142293/how-to-configure-ckeditor-in-rails-3-1-gem-asset-pipeline) but it doesn't work for me. Then I realized that the author of that link only create a new style of toolbar. You need to call it in the view also. That means you need to add this line

```
input_html => {:toolbar => 'MyToolbar'}
```

to make it works.

In order to test if the config.js is working, you can check the source of your webpage to see whether assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js is added. 
Another way to check is to edit the editor color by uncommenting this line: `config.uiColor = '#AADC6E'`. If the color of the editor changes then it works.

I also made a stupid mistake that I include the ckeditor js files two times: once in the application.js, once in the layouts/application.html.haml file. Don't know whether this is the source of the problem or not. You can try.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is for `simple_forms`.  For the Rails default, it's just an option in the the last HTML parameter, `:toolbar => 'MyToolbar'`.

Answer (score 5):

1.Add following in application.js

```
//= require ckeditor/ckeditor
//= require_tree ./ckeditor
```

2.Add a config.js in app/assets/javascript/ckeditor
Sample config.js

```
if(typeof(CKEDITOR) != 'undefined')
{
 CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
   config.uiColor = "#AADC6E";
   config.toolbar = [
    [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike' ],
    [ 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'HorizontalRule' ],
    [ 'Blockquote' ],
    [ 'Undo', 'Redo' ],
    [ 'insertResolved' ],
    [ 'Source' ]
 ];
}
} else{
  console.log("ckeditor not loaded")
}
```

Comment: This question may provide more information on what can be edited http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142293/how-to-configure-ckeditor-in-rails-3-1-gem-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:
[How to configure CKEditor in Rails 3.1 (gem + Asset Pipeline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142293/how-to-configure-ckeditor-in-rails-3-1-gem-asset-pipeline)
just save the snippet given in the answer, in config.js file

Comment: Well that was what I thought was going to work also but no joy.  Thanks for the try anyway

Answer (score 1):

May be my comment on github will help you https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/136#issuecomment-8870692

Answer (score 0):

This is the **updated** answer to **Rails 4.1** with **ckeditor 4.1.0** to custom configure the ckeditor toolbar.

In your view, using simple_form, you need to config the input like this example:

### _FORM.HTML.ERB

```
<%= simple_form_for(@foo) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :bar, as: :ckeditor %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

In your Javascript assets you need to create a folder called "ckeditor" and in there create a file called "config.js"

### ../JAVASCRIPTS/CKEDITOR/CONFIG.JS

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
  //config.language = 'es'; //this could be any language
  config.width = '725';
  config.height = '600';

  // Filebrowser routes
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
  config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
  config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
  config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";
  // The location of a script that handles file uploads.
  config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

// You could delete or reorder any of this elements as you wish
  config.toolbar_Menu = [
    { name: 'document', items: ['Source', '-', 'Save', 'NewPage', 'DocProps', 'Preview', 'Print', '-', 'Templates'] }, 
    { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] }, 
    { name: 'editing', items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', '-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt'] }, 
    { name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks', '-', 'About'] }, '/', 
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] }, 
    { name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl'] }, 
    { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] }, '/', 
    { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] }, 
    { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] }, 
    { name: 'insert', items: ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak'] }
  ];
  config.toolbar = 'Menu';
  return true;
};
```

The config for the application.js is like this, notice that the order of ckeditor and require_tree is **important**

### APPLICATION.JS

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require_tree .
```

Now in your ckeditor.rb you should uncomment this line "config.asset_path" and add the path to the config.js file that you created before wich is "/assets/ckeditor/"

### ../CONFIG/INITIALIZERS/CKEDITOR.RB

```
# Use this hook to configure ckeditor
Ckeditor.setup do |config|
  # ==> ORM configuration
  # Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default), :mongo_mapper and
  # :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
  # available as additional gems.
  require "ckeditor/orm/active_record"

  # Customize ckeditor assets path
  # By default: nil
  config.asset_path = "/assets/ckeditor/"
end
```

I hope it helps :D!