# Ckeditor in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor

I have added ckeditor(gem "ckeditor", "3.7.3") in my rails 3.2 app and is working fine.
But the problem is I want on specific things out of the whole toolbar , I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142293/how-to-configure-ckeditor-in-rails-3-1-gem-asset-pipeline/9199004#9199004).
[Here](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) it has mentioned two types of toolbar Full and Easy,where Easy is configued as shown [here](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js).

---

So the question is how do I get the information of all the variables so that I use only what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an `/app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor` directory and then a `config.js` file in that, you can add some customizations like this to make a minimal toolbar, note in this example I didn't want the document sections of NewPage and Preview:

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar=  [
//    { name: 'document', items : [ 'NewPage','Preview' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize','-','About' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format' ] },
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote' ] },
    { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] }

];
```

Note you may want to include the contents of the bundled config.js or things like the image uploader and file browser won't work.  Mine looks like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';

    /* Filebrowser routes */
    // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

    // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

    // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

    // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

    // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

    // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

    // The location of a script that handles file uploads.
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

    // Rails CSRF token
    config.filebrowserParams = function(){
        var csrf_token, csrf_param, meta,
            metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'),
            params = new Object();

        for ( var i = 0 ; i < metas.length ; i++ ){
            meta = metas[i];

            switch(meta.name) {
                case "csrf-token":
                    csrf_token = meta.content;
                    break;
                case "csrf-param":
                    csrf_param = meta.content;
                    break;
                default:
                    continue;
            }
        }

        if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
            params[csrf_param] = csrf_token;
        }

        return params;
    };

    config.addQueryString = function( url, params ){
        var queryString = [];

        if ( !params ) {
            return url;
        } else {
            for ( var i in params )
                queryString.push( i + "=" + encodeURIComponent( params[ i ] ) );
        }

        return url + ( ( url.indexOf( "?" ) != -1 ) ? "&" : "?" ) + queryString.join( "&" );
    };

    // Integrate Rails CSRF token into file upload dialogs (link, image, attachment and flash)
    CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ){
        // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
        var content, upload;

        if (CKEDITOR.tools.indexOf(['link', 'image', 'attachment', 'flash'], dialogName) > -1) {
            content = (dialogDefinition.getContents('Upload') || dialogDefinition.getContents('upload'));
            upload = (content == null ? null : content.get('upload'));

            if (upload && upload.filebrowser && upload.filebrowser['params'] === undefined) {
                upload.filebrowser['params'] = config.filebrowserParams();
                upload.action = config.addQueryString(upload.action, upload.filebrowser['params']);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Where did you get the source for the bundled config.js from? I was trying to review it to get a better understanding of my ckeditor, but I'm not having any luck.

Comment: @MichaelFok I believe it's from this blog: http://blog.antas.cz/config-js-or-why-i-like-ckeditor-that-much