# Integrate Dragonfly into CKeditor in Rails Admin with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, image-uploading, dragonfly-gem

I currently have CKeditor working splendid in my Rails Admin.

But now I want to enable image upload so users can insert own images. 
I read that this is possible with paperclip and carrierwave but I'm using **dragonfly** for a lot of things so I don't want to change that.

This is my CKeditor config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.toolbar_Toolbar =
    [
        { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','Underline','-','RemoveFormat'] },
        { name: 'justify', items : [ 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
        { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Format' ] },       
        { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','SpecialChar'] },
        '/',
        { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },        
        { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-'] },
        { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor', 'Source' ] }
    ];
    config.toolbar = 'Toolbar';
    config.allowedContent = true;
}
```

When I look to "Image" I don't see any way of uploading a file and I can't get even get a clear answer on the Github Page of the Ckeditor (https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor).

**IMPORTANT I'm using Rails version 3.2.13**

UPDATE 1:

I was reading on this page http://richonrails.com/articles/getting-started-with-ckeditor

And I tried rails generate ckeditor:install --orm=active_record --backend=dragonfly still no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching on StackOverflow and this solution worked for me :

[Ckeditor in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488358/ckeditor-in-rails-3)

Now my config.js looks like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.toolbar_Toolbar =
    [
        { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Strike','Underline','-','RemoveFormat'] },
        { name: 'justify', items : [ 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock' ] },
        { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Format' ] },       
        { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','SpecialChar','Insert','Tools'] },
        '/',
        { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },        
        { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-'] },
        { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor', 'Source' ] }
    ];
    config.toolbar = 'Toolbar';
    config.allowedContent = true;


     /* Filebrowser routes */
    // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed.
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

    // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Flash dialog.
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

    // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Flash dialog.
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

    // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Link tab of Image dialog.
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseLinkUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

    // The location of an external file browser, that should be launched when "Browse Server" button is pressed in the Image dialog.
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

    // The location of a script that handles file uploads in the Image dialog.
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/pictures";

    // The location of a script that handles file uploads.
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = "/ckeditor/attachment_files";

    // Rails CSRF token
    config.filebrowserParams = function(){
        var csrf_token, csrf_param, meta,
            metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'),
            params = new Object();

        for ( var i = 0 ; i < metas.length ; i++ ){
            meta = metas[i];

            switch(meta.name) {
                case "csrf-token":
                    csrf_token = meta.content;
                    break;
                case "csrf-param":
                    csrf_param = meta.content;
                    break;
                default:
                    continue;
            }
        }

        if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
            params[csrf_param] = csrf_token;
        }

        return params;
    };

    config.addQueryString = function( url, params ){
        var queryString = [];

        if ( !params ) {
            return url;
        } else {
            for ( var i in params )
                queryString.push( i + "=" + encodeURIComponent( params[ i ] ) );
        }

        return url + ( ( url.indexOf( "?" ) != -1 ) ? "&" : "?" ) + queryString.join( "&" );
    };

    // Integrate Rails CSRF token into file upload dialogs (link, image, attachment and flash)
    CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ){
        // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
        var content, upload;

        if (CKEDITOR.tools.indexOf(['link', 'image', 'attachment', 'flash'], dialogName) > -1) {
            content = (dialogDefinition.getContents('Upload') || dialogDefinition.getContents('upload'));
            upload = (content == null ? null : content.get('upload'));

            if (upload && upload.filebrowser && upload.filebrowser['params'] === undefined) {
                upload.filebrowser['params'] = config.filebrowserParams();
                upload.action = config.addQueryString(upload.action, upload.filebrowser['params']);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @SachinSingh yes but only in rails 3.